# Merge table PHP and table Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a table in PHP and I have another table in Javascript. I would like to add Elements of the table PHP  to elements Javascript table.
I tried with the push method :

```
<?php



$tabPHP=['5963','3652'];

?>



<script> 
  tabJS =["PARIS","AUBERVILLIERS","ARGENTEUIL","NANTERRE"];
  tabJS.push(<?php print_r(tabPHP); ?>);
</script> 


tabJS.push (   $tabPHP  ) ;
```

but it does not work, is what you have ideas for my problem.

Comment: `table` in javascript ? Can you share your code too ?

Comment: Edit your question and include your code + what you have tried in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to iterate over each element of the array in php and push each single element to the js array

```
<?php
$tabPHP=['5963','3652'];
?>
<script>

tabJS =["PARIS","AUBERVILLIERS","ARGENTEUIL","NANTERRE"];

<?php 

foreach ($tabPHP as $value) {
    echo "tabJS.push(".$value.");";
}
?>
</script>
```